App is not sandboxed
I try to open camera from Apps section. Then it is giving this message " Camera not found". In the top it is displaying "App is not sandboxed"
How to solve this issue?


Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

According to the Linux Surface Wiki, people were not able to reverse engineer the camera driver  for Surface Pro 7, and Microsoft did not make the camera drivers available.
While the sandbox issue may be prevented by installing Cheese instead of the default GNOME Camera app, that will not fix the underlying issue, that the kernel cannot detect the camera due to unavailability of drivers.
Being an APT app, Cheese should not have any sandbox issues, and you can use cheese with an external webcam.
sudo apt install cheese


Can someone explain their downvote?

Tried installing cheese. "No device found". Mine is microsoft surface pro 7. whether drivers are available ?

Ok. I did some search about surface pro 7, and turns out microsoft did not make camera drivers available for Linux. I updated my answer.

Thank you Archisman
